# Different outcome google maps and google maps api directions

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the following request by the Google Maps API:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=-25.4105796,-49.248257&destination=-25.4356342,-49.2566111&language=pt-BR&sensor=false&mode=transit&departure_time=12

So far so right, the problem that this response is not equal to answer that google gives me direct from google maps, sample site:

[https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir/'-25.4105796,-49.248257'/'-25.4356342,-49.2566111'/@-25.4176209,-49.2401364,13z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m12!4m11!1m3!2m2!1d-49.248257!2d-25.4105796!1m3!2m2!1d-49.2566111!2d-25.4356342!2m1!6e4!3e3](https://www.google.com.br/maps/dir/%27-25.4105796,-49.248257%27/%27-25.4356342,-49.2566111%27/@-25.4176209,-49.2401364,13z/am=t/data=!3m1!4b1!4m12!4m11!1m3!2m2!1d-49.248257!2d-25.4105796!1m3!2m2!1d-49.2566111!2d-25.4356342!2m1!6e4!3e3)

I've tried with other parameters of origin and destination, both for the request as json maps by itself, however the result is never the same.

This request directions via the api is still valid even with the updated maps to version 3?

Or am I making the request to the wrong url?

Thank you.

Comment: The [API looks like it returns the same result to me](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=(-25.4105796,-49.248257)&addr2=(-25.4356342,-49.2566111)&trvlmode=transit&departure_time=12&geocode=1&geocode=2); I can't parse that JSON response to see what is different.

Comment: Thanks for the response, then the link you posted is how I wish, that result is right, however the json response is different, do not appear the same data, I'll post here the json result: 

http://pastebin.com/Ge1czxyp 

In this example, JSON does not contain such a tube Agricultural Station. 

Like other tests I did, the result is different from one another. 

Thank you.